# Images compressed with Imagick do not pass the PageSpeed test

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

What parameters can I add to Imagick to improve image compression?

Even with this code, Google's PageSpeed ​​continues to accuse the images of need reduction.

```
$image = new \Imagick($request->img->path());
$image->setImageFormat('jpg');
$fileName = date('YmdHis') . microtime(true) . rand(111111111, 999999999) . '.' . $image->getImageFormat();
$image->setImageCompressionQuality(70);
$image->stripImage();
$image->setSamplingFactors(array('2x2', '1x1', '1x1'));
$image->setInterlaceScheme(\Imagick::INTERLACE_JPEG);
$image->setColorspace(\Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);
$image->writeImage($path . '/' . $fileName);
$image->destroy();
```

Comment: What if you lower `setImageCompressionQuality`?

Comment: Is already in the limit, if I lower more, the image quality gets low.

Comment: Try putting the strip before setting the quality. Also move the setColorspace to right after reading the image. This may not change anything but give it a try.

Comment: @DiegoVieira What is the original resolution of the image? And what resolution is it being displayed as on page? This may be what they are talking about. If you're forcing the browser to download an image that is 3 times wider than the browser's width, that could be why Google is yelling at you.

Comment: The problem isn't the resolution, but the compression. Linkto pageSpeed: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=pt-br&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.infochat.com.br%2Fbusca%2Fporto-alegre%2Frs%2Ftodos%2Flemos&tab=desktop